# install release's apk after installed debug's apk ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I created a Ionic App and installed a debug apk of App on device.
I build a release apk of App and transfer to device and Trying to install the App but not install.
I remove debug version of device and then installing release apk be installed correctly.
how to create a release apk install on Which if the debug version is installed without remove debug version of device ?

Comment: If you want to have both a release and a debug version installed on the device you should change the debug app id. That way you can have them both installed.

Comment: reply cata  ,No , I want to install the release version on the debug version

Comment: Ah, ok, well did you checked if the apks are signed with the same key?